# Quickly generating test data (UUIDs, large random numbers, etc) with bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have a small bash script with a function containing a case statement which echoes random data if the 1st argument matches the case parameter.
Code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash   '

AC='auto-increment'                                                                                                    
UUID='uuid'                                                                                                            
LAT='lat'                                                                                                              
LONG='long'                                                                                                            
IP='ip'

generate_mock_data() {                                                                                                 
# ARGS: $1 - data type, $2 - loop index                                                                              
case ${1} in                                                                                                         
    ${AC})                                                                                                             
        echo ${2} ;;                                                                                                     
    ${UUID})                                                                                                           
        uuidgen ;;                                                                                                       
    ${LAT})                                                                                                            
        echo $((RANDOM % 180 - 90)).$(shuf -i1000000-9999999 -n1) ;;                                                     
    ${LONG})                                                                                                           
        echo $((RANDOM % 360 - 180)).$(shuf -i1000000-9999999 -n1) ;;                                                    
    ${IP})                                                                                                             
        echo $((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)) ;;                                          
esac                                                                                                                 
}

# Writing data to file                                             
headers=('auto-increment' 'uuid' 'lat' 'long' 'ip')                
for i in {1..2500}; do                                             
  for header in "${headers[@]}"; do                                
    echo -n $(generate_mock_data ${header} ${i}),                  
  done                                                             
echo  # New line                                                 
done >> file.csv
```

However, execution time is incredibly slow for just 2500 rows:

`real    0m8.876s
user    0m0.576s
sys     0m0.868s`

What am I doing wrong ? is there anything I can do to speed up the process ? or is bash not the right language for these type of operations ?
I also tried profiling the entire script but after looking at the logs I didn't notice any significant bottlenecks.

Comment: You have started 1500 processes in 8.9 seconds... Three out of five calls to `generate_mock_data` run an external program; that program needs to be loaded from disk (or more likely cache), initialized, and run to completion.

Comment: `echo $(...)` is just a long way of writing `...`. Have the function use `echo -n` (or preferably, `printf`) to output strings without a newline.

Comment: Also, you are overgeneralizing; you always call `generate_mock_data` once per header item; just have each all output a full row instead of calling it 5 separate times.

Comment: Finally, you should probably use `awk` for something like this; then you would have a *single* process to generate every row, with just one additional call to `uuidgen` for each row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, much obliged. Any code samples would be appreciated .

Comment: Do you really need the `uuidgen` in there - my system takes 8s to generate 2,500 uuids anyway - without doing anything else. Would some other form of random number be acceptable?

Comment: No I do not insist on using uuidgen, I just figured since its builtin it's probably fast. I'll try using something else instead.

Comment: `$(...)` has a lot of overhead. Just calling `generate_mock_data "${header}" "${i}"` without the command substitution would help.

Comment: ...well, that would have been the overwhelming source of most of your overhead *if you weren't using an external `uuidgen` command*. Since you are, command invocations are going to be eating more time than anything else.

Comment: ...`shuf` is expensive too -- anything that's not a bash builtin, in general, should never be used from an inner loop. (What you *can* do is create a file descriptor from which you can read a stream of contents written from a single external invocation, and read one line from it per invocation -- done properly, that way you're only paying process startup overhead once).

Comment: @EvyatarMeged, `uuidgen` is *not* built-in to bash. ("builtins" are commands that the shell has an implementation of in-process, and they *are* indeed fast; tools like `uuidgen`, `ls`, `awk`, `shuf`, etc. are provided by your OS vendor, not by bash, so invoking them requires starting up a separate process each time they're called).

Comment: btw, `${foo}` gives you no correctness benefit over `$foo`, whereas `"$foo"` or `"${foo}"` is more correct than either -- suppressing word-splitting and globbing of expansion results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can generate a UUID pretty fast with Python, so if you just execute Python once to generate 2,500 UUIDs, and you aren't a Python programmer -like me ;-) then you can patch them up with `awk`:

```
python -c 'import uuid; print("\n".join([str(uuid.uuid4()).upper() for x in range(2500)]))' |
   awk '{
      lat=-90+180*rand();
      lon=-180+360*rand();
      ip=int(256*rand()) "." int(256*rand()) "." int(256*rand()) "." int(256*rand());
      print NR,$0,lat,lon,ip
  }' OFS=,
```

This takes 0.06s on my iMac.

- `OFS` is the *"Output Field Separator"*
- `NR` is the line number
- $0 means *"the whole input line"*

You can try the Python on its own, like this:

```
python -c 'import uuid; print("\n".join([str(uuid.uuid4()).upper() for x in range(2500)]))'
```

Comment: Nice. I was about to write an optimized bash implementation, but saw the `shuf` and `uuidgen` and decided it wasn't worth the time -- this is a practical, solid, readable alternative.

Comment: (Well -- it's *not* worth the time, but I'm doing so anyhow. Still, this is a really great answer. :))

Comment: I want to thank you both kind gentlemen for your help. I've accepted Mark's answer only because it wins the speed test - generating 100K rows takes little under 1.3s opposed to Charles' refined bash script with +-19s.

Answer (score 3):

#### Is Shell The Right Tool?

Not really, but if you avoid bad practices, you can make something *relatively* fast.

With ksh93, the below reliably runs in 0.5-0.6s wall-clock; with bash, 1.2-1.3s.

#### What Does It Look Like?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Comment these two lines if running with ksh93, obviously. :)
[ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]         && { echo "This requires bash 4.1 or newer" >&2; exit 1; }
[[ $BASH_VERSION = [123].* ]]  && { echo "This requires bash 4.1 or newer" >&2; exit 1; }

uuid_stream() {
  python -c '
import uuid
try:
  while True:
    print str(uuid.uuid4()).upper()
except IOError:
    pass # probably an EPIPE because we were closed.
'
}

# generate a file descriptor that emits a shuffled stream of integers
exec {large_int_fd}< <(while shuf -r -i1000000-9999999; do :; done)

# generate a file descriptor that emits an endless stream of UUIDs
exec {uuid_fd}< <(uuid_stream)

generate_mock_data() {
  typeset val
  case $1 in
    auto-increment)  val="$2" ;;
    uuid)            IFS= read -r val <&"$uuid_fd" || exit;;
    lat)             IFS= read -r val <&"$large_int_fd" || exit
                     val="$((RANDOM % 180 - 90)).$val" ;;
    long)            IFS= read -r val <&"$large_int_fd" || exit
                     val="$((RANDOM % 360 - 180)).$val" ;;
    ip)              val="$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256))" ;; 
  esac
  printf '%s' "$val"
}

for ((i=0; i<2500; i++)); do                                             
  for header in auto-increment uuid lat long ip; do
    generate_mock_data "$header" "$i"
    printf ,
  done
  echo
done > file.csv
```

---

#### What's Different?

- **There are no command substitutions inside the inner loop.** That means we don't ever use `$()` or any synonym for same. Each of these involves a `fork()` -- creating a new OS-level copy of the process -- and a `wait()`, with a bunch of FIFO magic to capture our output.
- **There are no external commands inside the inner loop.** Any external command is even worse than a command substitution: They require a fork, and then *additionally* require an `execve`, with the dynamic linker and loader being invoked to pull in all the library dependencies for whichever external command is being run.
- **Because we don't have a command substitution stripping newlines, we have the function just not emitting them.**

Comment: Not bad ;-)  ;-)  ;-)